# Additional information: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, t-sql

I am trying to execute this command from my .net App, however I get this error

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```
INSERT INTO TempSense_AppEngine_Medidas (Valor, FechaHora, DispositivoI) VALUES(CONVERT(decimal(38,2), REPLACE('26,8',',','.')),  CONVERT(Datetime, '15/11/2016 13:16:07', 120),6)
```

and this is my code

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TempsenseConnection2"].ConnectionString))
                                    {
                                        sqlConn.Open();
                                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                                        cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TempSense_AppEngine_Medidas (Valor, FechaHora, DispositivoI) VALUES(CONVERT(decimal(38,2), REPLACE('" + medida.Valor + "',',','.')),  CONVERT(Datetime, '" + medida.FechaHora + "', 120)," + medida.DispositivoID + ")";
                                        //cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TempSense_AppEngine_Dispositivo (DispositivoI) VALUES(" + medida.DispositivoID + ")";
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converstion type 103 to convert dd/mm/yyyy

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '15/11/2016 13:16:07', 103)
```

Returns

```
2016-11-15 13:16:07.000
```